# Build a View/Table-Valued UDF for views in another DB

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, view, user-defined-functions

There are ~10 views in a different DB that I need to pull data from. Currently, my team is passing a string to the SQL `EXEC` command. I know there is a better way. The local DB has data for the legacy software and the "different" DB has the data for the new software. We are combining the two. The newer software also creates a new DB for every client/project with identical structures.

Optimally, I would like to create triggers on each of the 10 views that inserts into an already existing table in our local DB. My problem here is that views can only have `INSTEAD OF` triggers and I would need a `AFTER` trigger so that the DB would still perform normally.

Another method I am considering is a Table-Valued UDF. My biggest setback on this one is that the legacy software uses unique ID's whereas the the new software doesn't (for the fields I am fetching).

Is there another way that I am not seeing or any improvements to these methods?

I'll post a pseudo-example below - 
I have one DB with a table (for example) called car-parts along with a bunch of stored procedures and views that use said table. In another DB, I have 10 tables that each represent a car part (engine, muffler, seats, etc.) that need to be consolidated and used similar to the car-parts table. For each new manufacturing product, the modeling software creates a new DB for those 10 tables.

Right now we are doing something like

```
DECLARE @SQLCmd varchar(max) = '
    SELECT * FROM [''' + @DynamicTableName + '''].[dbo].[Engine] 
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM [''' + @DynamicTableName + '''].[dbo].[Muffler]
    ... '
EXEC(@SQLCmd)
```

The ID's in car-parts can be unique, whereas the ID's in the 10 tables may not be so assume they cannot be used.

Comment: linked server ?

Comment: So we don't need a linked server because all DBs are on the same server. I forgot to mention that the new software also uses dynamic DBs so we will have multiple DBs representing multiple clients/projects. This is why we have resorted to the strings in the EXEC. I will add this to the question.

Comment: "dynamic DBs": if you don't know ahead of time what DBs you're going to select from, then you're going to end up doing some dynamic SQL. The only alternative is to assemble the SQL statements in the application rather than in the database.

Comment: I see. Where would you say is the best place to put this dynamic SQL in order to reduce the amount of times I have to repeat the same code? For example, if I have 4 or 5 procedures that need access to that dynamic SQL for a join, I'm trying to avoid copy pasting the same code.

Answer (score 0):

So I'll put our solution on here just in case some poor soul ends up in a similar situation. Note: This is not the only way to handle this, just the way we decided to use.

We ended up creating a stored proc to pull all the data from the 10 tables on the dynamic DB. This proc inserts said data into a temp table which is created by the "parent" stored proc that needs the data for joins and whatnot. This looks something like -

**Parent Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE TABLE #DynamicData
( 
    ID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER,
    Name varchar(50),
    ...
)

EXEC GetDynamicData @Params=@Params

SELECT * FROM #DynamicData
    JOIN LocalTable on ...
```

**Child Stored Procedure**

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName varchar(50)

SELECT @DatabaseName = DatabaseName
    FROM Project A 
    JOIN Users U on A.UID=U.Project
    where U.EmailAddress = @CurrentUser

DECLARE @SQLCmd varchar(max)=
    'SELECT UID AS ID, Name ... FROM 
    (
        SELECT UID, Name, ... FROM [' + @DatabaseName + '].[dbo].[View1]
        UNION
        SELECT UID, Name, ... FROM [' + @DatabaseName + '].[dbo].[View2]
        UNION
        ...
    ) Items'

INSERT INTO #DynamicData EXEC @SQLCmd
```

A big benefit of doing it this way has been that the columns are "solidified" by the time they hit the Parent Stored Procedure. In the Child, they are just strings so there is no suggestions, compile errors, etc. It can be quite a pain to edit things in the Child, but as long as you have a solid idea of what columns you are looking for.